# powerShell is returning minus int?

Tags: powershell, int

I have two loops:

```
$computer = $args[0]

$colProcData = @()
$procs = get-process -computername $computer | sort -descending "WorkingSet" | select -first 3
foreach($proc in $procs)
{
    $machine = $proc.MachineName
    $process = [String]$proc.ProcessName
    $WorkingSet = [int64]($proc.WorkingSet64/1024)
    $id = $proc.Id
    $CPU = ($proc.CPU)

    $procdata = new-object psobject
    $procdata | add-member noteproperty machine $machine
    $procdata | add-member noteproperty process $process
    $procdata | add-member noteproperty usedRam-MB $WorkingSet 
    $procdata | add-member noteproperty id $id
    $procdata | add-member noteproperty CPU $CPU

    $colProcData += $procdata
}
$colProcData | Sort-Object usedRam-MB -descending  | Format-Table -AutoSize  | out-default



$colProcData = @()
$procs = get-process -computername $computer | sort -descending "WorkingSet" | select -last 3
foreach($proc in $procs)
{
    $machine = $proc.MachineName
    $process = [String]$proc.ProcessName
    $WorkingSet = [int64]($proc.WorkingSet64/1024)
    $id = $proc.Id
    $CPU = ($proc.CPU)

    $procdata = new-object psobject
    $procdata | add-member noteproperty machine $machine
    $procdata | add-member noteproperty process $process
    $procdata | add-member noteproperty usedRam-MB $WorkingSet
    $procdata | add-member noteproperty id $id
    $procdata | add-member noteproperty CPU $CPU

    $colProcData += $procdata
}
$colProcData | Sort-Object usedRam-MB -descending  | Format-Table -AutoSize  | out-default
```

Tho only difference is first/last. When I run "`.\scriptName.ps1 systemName`"  I get:

```
process    usedRam-MB   id CPU
-------    ----------   -- ---
mysqld         135812 1692
WmiPrvSE        79560 6184
powershell      51724 6644



process  usedRam-MB   id CPU
-------  ----------   -- ---
LogonUI         264  580
Idle             24    0
sqlservr   -1987392 1640
```

**How can I get rid of that minus?** Just for info: systemName is remote computer, not localhost! If I run it on localhost I get no minus:

```
process  usedRam-MB   id CPU
-------  ----------   -- ---
mysqld       135888 1692
WmiPrvSE      80508 6184
svchost       50720  832



process  usedRam-MB   id CPU
-------  ----------   -- ---
sqlservr   10618744 1640
LogonUI         264  580
Idle             24    0
```

Also for info :

> memory total on systemName: 12.000 MB

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

What's the value of WorkingSet64 before you divide it? Does this produce a positive number?

```
$WorkingSet = $proc.WorkingSet64/1mb
```

By the way, the current expression get's th result in KB (divided once by 1024)

Comment: You can restrict the number of decimal points: $WorkingSet = '{0:N0} -f '$proc.WorkingSet64/1mb  . What's the value of WorkingSet64 when you look at it on the server itself?

Comment: Is the server in question a 32 bit machine?

Comment: on server :  sqlservr 10415,43359375

Comment: The line `$WorkingSet = '{0:N0} -f '$proc.WorkingSet64/1mb` is not working

Comment: $WorkingSet = '{0:N0} -f $proc.WorkingSet64/1mb

Comment: Are you using the x86 instance of PowerShell to query the servers?

Comment: I am using 64 bit instance of PowerShell.

Comment: I heard about cases where this may happen when the amount of memory is greater than 2gb, but I don't know for sure

Answer (score 0):

You could use the .Net ABS function:

```
[Math]::Abs($WorkingSet)
```

Comment: `[Math]::Abs($WorkingSet)` return 0

Comment: If i usee `[Math]::Abs(-2.002)` it simply return  `2,002`. Correct would be something like `10.286` because I have 12.000 gb ram-a.